# Any way I can optimize these sql scripts?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a script that is going out and correcting two fields that are not enabled on one table in our database.  The script is running against a table with over 400k rows and it takes forever to run.

```
USE <DB>
GO

update ApplicationAnswers set Enabled = 1
where QuestionID = 1778 and AwardYearID in(9,10) 

update ApplicationAnswers set Enabled = 1
where QuestionID = 1212 and AwardYearID in(9,10)
```

Anyway I can optimize this to run more efficiently?  Let me know if you need more information.  I have asked the DBA's here and have not heard back from them.  Thanks

Comment: Do you have an index on those columns in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: I think maybe that is the missing part of the formula I will try both suggestions

Comment: Are there triggers on the table?  sp_helptrigger 'ApplicationAnswers'

Comment: No triggers on this table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set an index in `QuestionID` and also in `AwardYearID`

```
CREATE INDEX index_for_QuestionID ON ApplicationAnswers(QuestionId);

CREATE INDEX index_for_AwardYearID ON ApplicationAnswers(AwardYearID);
```

Also, combining both updates in one shot, as [Hitham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/643500/hitham-s-alqadheeb) suggests:

```
UPDATE schemaName.dbo.ApplicationAnswers SET Enabled = 1
WHERE QuestionID IN (1212,1778) AND AwardYearID in(9,10)
```

Comment: Indexes might help, but my hunch would be that neither QuestionID or AwardYearID would have the selectivity required to actually utilize an index. If you do implement a new index, be sure to check the explain plan before and after to ensure the compilier is hitting it. Else, remove it.

Comment: Totally agree, toddnappi. Thanks for your remark, which I find very useful.

Comment: Alright I am running this is a dev environment that is not being hit by much so we shall see what happens.  I appreciate all the suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

The only optimization I see is to directly reference the table

```
schemaName.dbo.ApplicationAnswers
```

Then combine them

```
update schemaName.dbo.ApplicationAnswers set Enabled = 1
where QuestionID in (1212,1778)  and AwardYearID in(9,10)
```

Comment: Thanks I will give it a shot and will report back after it runs..will be awhile.

Comment: Indeed then you have one full scan instead of two full scans but what is really needed is an index instead, as said above.